# Why does object "requestContext" become null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, oop

Until this point the object `requestContext` has some property values inside it but after the execution of the method `ValidityCheck()` the `requestContext` has been set to `null` value. Can someone help me to understand why the `requestContext` becomes `null`

````
public class TravelService : AbstractService, ITravelService

 public long PurchaseTripsAsynchronous(List<TravelOption> travelOptionList, User user, List<Passenger> passengersList, TravelRequest travelRequest, string siteURL, string sessionID,
             bool isLoggedIn, string currencyCode, bool isGroupBooking = false, CreditCard CC = null, PaymentRequest request =null,UserRequestContext requestContext = null)
         {
           
 
             long travelRequestId = (travelRequest == null) ? 0 : travelRequest.Id;
             try
             {
                 VaultService _vaultService = new VaultService(_siteDbConfiguration);
                 SiteContext siteContext = _vaultService.GetSiteConfiguration(siteURL, requestContext: requestContext);
                 CCVerificationStatus ccStatus;
                 AuthorizeDotNetService authorizeDotNet = new AuthorizeDotNetService(_siteDbConfiguration);
                 if (CC != null && request !=null)
                 {
                     if (creditCardValidationV2.IsCreditCardVerificationServiceON(LogType.PURCHASE, requestContext) && CC.CreditCardType == (int)creditCardTypeKey.Corporate)
                     {
                         ccStatus = creditCardValidationV2.CheckSabreCreditCardService(request, siteContext, travelRequestId, LogType.PURCHASE, requestContext);
                         travelRequest.CreditCardError = ccStatus.errorMsg;
                         if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccStatus.errorMsg) && ccStatus.errorMsg.Length < 0) || ccStatus.status == true)
                         {
                             bool IsValidCard = true;
                             string strngMsg = string.Empty;
  IsValidCard = authorizeDotNet.ValidityCheck(request, siteContext, out strngMsg, travelRequestId, LogType.PURCHASE, requestContext);
                             if (IsValidCard == false)
                             {
                                 travelRequest.CreditCardError = SharedConstants.SABRE_CC_ErrorMsg;
                             }
                         }
 
 
                     }
 
                 }```

 ```C#
 public class AuthorizeDotNetService : AbstractService
 
     public bool ValidityCheck(PaymentRequest request, SiteContext siteContext, out string strMsg, long travelRequestId = 0, LogType logType = LogType.NONE, UserRequestContext requestContext = null)
                 {
                     LogWriter.WriteAuditLog("Start Calling : =======> " + "AuthorizeDotNetService->ValidityCheck", LogLevel.DEBUG, logType: logType, requestContext: requestContext);
                     strMsg = "";
                     string CardNumber = "";
                     string ExpirationMonthAndYear = "";
                     string CVVNumber = "";
                     string CustomerIpAddress = "";
                     string FirstName = "";
                     string LastName = "";
                     string Address = "";
                     string StateName = "";
                     string ZipCode = "";
                     try
                     {
                         CardNumber = request.CreditCardNumber;
                         ExpirationMonthAndYear = request.ExpirationMonthAndYear;
                         CVVNumber = request.CCVNumber;
                         CustomerIpAddress = request.CustomerIpAddress;
                         FirstName = request.CustomerFirstName;
                         LastName = request.CustomerLastName;
                         Address = request.BillingAddress1 + " " + request.BillingAddress2;
                         StateName = request.BillingState;
                         ZipCode = request.BillingZipCode;
     
                     ConnectorDBManager manager = ConnectorDBManager.GetInstance();
                     manager.ConnectionId = siteContext.Module.Travel.GDS.AuthorizeDotNet.ConnectionKey;
                     ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = manager.GetConnectionInfo();
     
                     var Request = new AuthorizationRequest(CardNumber, ExpirationMonthAndYear, 0.01M, connectionInfo.Environment, false);
     
     
     
     
     
                     // ADD CVV NUMBER
                     Request.AddCardCode(CVVNumber);
                     // ADD CUSTOMER IP ADDRESS FOR FRAUD CHECKING
                     Request.AddFraudCheck(CustomerIpAddress);
     
                     // ADD BILLING INFORMATION
                     Request.AddCustomer("1", FirstName, LastName, Address, StateName, ZipCode);
     
                     Request.DuplicateWindow = "0";
     
                     //var gate = new Gateway("798m6J4bW7g", "63bRHb6Ut32v6Lcy", true);
                     //var gate = new Gateway("7n22GuW5", "76s6tH6gG6Q6NY7g", true);
                     bool isTestMode = false;
                     if (connectionInfo.Environment.ToUpper() == "TEST")
                     {
                         isTestMode = true;
                     }
     
     
                     var gate = new Gateway(connectionInfo.UserId, connectionInfo.Password, isTestMode);
                     try
                     {
                         LogWriter.WriteAuditLog("Request==>" + Request.ToPostString(), LogLevel.INFO, _event: "AuthorizeDotNetService==>ValidityCheck", requestContext: requestContext);//added by sanman to investigate Logs of AuthorizeDotNetService
                     }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                     {
     
                     }
                     LogWriter.AuditWebServiceLog(Request.ToPostString(), LogLevel.AUDIT, true, logType: LogType.NONE, requestContext: requestContext);
                     //LogWriter.AuditWebServiceLog(Request.ToPostString(), LogLevel.DEBUG, true, travelRequestId, logType: logType); Samir needs to work on it
                     DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
                     var Response = gate.Send(Request);
                     LogWriter.WriteAuditPerformance(startDate, DateTime.Now, SLACategory.Booking, SLASubCategory.Air, connector: GdsSource.AuthorizeDotNet, page: "Payment", apiName: "ValidityCheck", requestContext: requestContext);
                     //LogWriter.AuditWebServiceLog(Response, LogLevel.AUDIT, true, logType: LogType.NONE, requestContext: requestContext);
                     
     
                     try
                     {
                         LogWriter.WriteAuditLog("Response JSON ==>" + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Response), LogLevel.INFO, _event: "AuthorizeDotNetService==>ValidityCheck", requestContext: requestContext);
     
                     }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                     {
                         LogWriter.WriteAuditLog("Response==>" + Response.ToString(), LogLevel.INFO, _event: "AuthorizeDotNetService==>ValidityCheck", requestContext: requestContext);
                     }
                     bool isValid = false;
                     if (Response != null)
                     {
                         strMsg = Response.Message;
                         int ResponseCode = Convert.ToInt32(Response.ResponseCode);
                         int ResponseReasonCode = GetReasonCode(Response, requestContext);
     
                         strMsg = strMsg + " (" + ResponseCode.ToString() + "," + ResponseReasonCode.ToString() + ")";
     
                         if (Shared.SharedUtils.IsProceedMessage(ResponseReasonCode))
                         {
                             var voidRequest = new VoidRequest(Response.TransactionID);
                             var voidResponse = gate.Send(voidRequest);
                             isValid = true;
                         }
     
                         LogWriter.WriteAuditLog("AUTHORIZE.NET VALIDITY CHECK " + strMsg + ", IsValid = " + isValid.ToString() + " --- > ", LogLevel.ERROR, logType: logType, requestContext: requestContext);
                     }
     
                      return isValid;
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     LogWriter.WriteAuditLog(ex.Message, LogLevel.ERROR, exception: ex, logType: logType);
                     throw ex;
                 }
                 finally
                 {
                     LogWriter.WriteAuditLog("End Calling : =======> " + "AuthorizeDotNetService->ValidityCheck", LogLevel.DEBUG, requestContext: requestContext, logType: logType);
                 }
             }```
````

Comment: I see that you call it in a thread - for me its no reason to add a new thread for `PurchaseTripsAsynchronous` because all ready is on a web thread- At some point this thread is cut out of the page (because the page continues and returns) and the `requestContext` is lost.

Comment: Can u explain it a bit elaborately,i made an edit both thse function are in different classes

Comment: How can i fix the issue

Comment: Remove any new thread call, and direct call the `PurchaseTripsAsynchronous` and see if works - or else you must find some other way to send the data from the browser to your task